# In onclick event how to add background image?

Tags: jquery, image, onclick

When the link is clicked I want to add the background image for active link.
This is my code but is not working..

HTML

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:7%;" align="center">
      <a href="Home.aspx"  id="DashboarHome">Home</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:9%;" align="center">
      <a href="Request.aspx"  id="Dashboard">Requests</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:66%;" align="center">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the alerts do work - so try and change the CSS of the `<a>` links. Give them a predefined width and height and make them `display: inline-block;` and then check.

Comment: remove the alert you are good to go :D

Comment: Should work (in case images are there - and you closed the alert). As a tipp: Instead of writing CSS with JavaScript it might be easier to maintain to define a CSS class in your stylesheet and add/ remove this class via JS.

Comment: the links seem to redirect somewhere else, that's why they won't apply classes on the old page

Comment: based on that href value i want to apply the image.anyone please give me some code example.

Comment: Your page reloads as you follow the links therefore any js you have applied will be lost on the new page.  You either have to store the state of the link in local storage which you can then load on the new page, or use a server side language to set the active state of links depending upon the url you are on

Answer (score 0):

Hi check out this fiddle I have prepared for you...however I'll suggest the background image of a container changes when links change instead of the active links. 
https://jsfiddle.net/samcyn/hyqqo84a/

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:7%;" align="center">
      <a href="#" class="content_menu" id="DashboardH" data-image="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/H8Y9KX8GYAk/hqdefault.jpg">Home</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:9%;" align="center">
      <a href="#" class="content_menu" id="DashboardREQ" data-image="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg">Requests</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:66%;" align="center">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="check">
</div>

const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
const check = document.getElementById('check');
function clickHandler(){
    //alert(this.dataset.image);
  //here's what you wanted
 // this.style.backgroundImage = `url(${this.dataset.image})`;
 //my suggestion
 check.style.backgroundImage = `url(${this.dataset.image})`;

}
links.forEach(function(link){
  link
```

.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});

Comment: my case for all link background image is same. i need to get the current page url and back of text i need to apply the image

Comment: can you please help me on this

Comment: I really don't understand you. It'll be fair if you have a fiddle or something I can really see. Also try to give vivid description of what you want to achieve.